# Get File First Sector Address

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET 2010.

I need to know the first sector address of a given file path. Is that possible using VB.NET?

I gone through google, but did not find any.

Comment: If I given the File Path: C:\foo\bar.txt, then I need to get the First sector on the disk where this file is stored in.

Comment: With visual basic?  That is more than impossible.;) It takes a lot of work to do that on even low level languages like assembly or c.

Comment: Is it possible to read the allocation table to get the address using VB.NET?

Comment: What do you think you'll be *able to do* if you do manage to retrieve some magic number that purports to be the first sector address?

Comment: I need to save that address, and then I can now if the file is moved to some where else by checking the start sector.

Comment: Wouldn't that File be referenced by a different path/device when it's moved? You can also set a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) to both observe changes and track it.

Comment: @Jimi - and on the other hand, if a hard link is made from another directory and then the original link removed, it may have been moved (in path terms) but maintain the *same* "sector" address. We still don't have enough information to understand the *overarching* motivation here.

Comment: It may be moved to another PC to the same Path. I need to know that grammatically, if the app is moved, then need to check that.

Comment: Right, so your actual *problem* has nothing to do with files and "sectors", but you want to detect if a file has moved between machines. Do you see how, if you had asked a question *about that*, you might get better results?

Comment: And your proposed way of solving the problem would also mean the disk could never be defragged.

Comment: You can check the machine name an combine this information with a file path if you need it. Maybe add a better definition of what *if the app is moved* should imply in you scenario. Possibly add these details editing your question @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Yes, that's a question+suggestion which usually *forces* an explanation of what is actually going on :)

Comment: FATs (File Allocation Tables) are managed by the OS and can't be read by ring 3  programs such as the ones created in vb.Try reading up rings of operating systems.